# Bootstrapping spark-avro jar to Amazon EMR cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-emr, spark-avro

I want to read avro files located in Amazon S3 from the Zeppelin notebook. I understand Databricks has a wonderful package for it `spark-avro`. What are the steps that I need to take in order to bootstrap this jar file to my cluster and make it working?

When I write this in my notebook, 

`val df = sqlContext.read.avro("s3n://path_to_avro_files_in_one_bucket/")`

I get the below error -

`<console>:34: error: value avro is not a member of org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader`

I have had a look at [this](https://github.com/databricks/spark-avro/issues/91). I guess the solution posted there does not work for the latest version of Amazon EMR.

If someone could give me pointers, that would really help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I associate the spark-avro dependencies. This method works for associating any other dependencies to spark.

1. Make sure your spark version is compatible with your spark-avro. You'll find the details of the dependencies [here](https://github.com/databricks/spark-avro).
2. I put my spark-avro file in my S3 bucket. You can use hdfs or any other store.
3. While launching an EMR cluster, add the following JSON in the configuration,
   `[{"classification":"spark-defaults", "properties":{"spark.files":"/path_to_spark-avro_jar_file", "spark.jars":"/path_to_spark-avro_jar_file"}, "configurations":[]}]`

This is not the only way to do this. Please refer this [link](https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.5.0-incubating/interpreter/spark.html) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

One more option is to add the --dependencies option to either spark-shell or spark submit (this is for spark 2.x)

> --packages com.databricks:spark-avro_2.11:4.0.0